# Display in input text instead of div

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I follow the http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/getlatlng.html

instead of displaying the 'latlng' in ,

how do i display it in

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly (.ie the lat/long value is appearing in the div below the map and you want it to appear in the input text field at the top) then you should change the following line of Javascript (Line 75)

```
document.getElementById('latlng').innerHTML = latlng;
```

to

```
document.getElementById('address').value = latlng;
```

Comment: Maybe you should consider selected this answer as the solution then :-)